# SSH接続してvimを実行すると、Ctrl-Cを押下しないと起動しない

Tags: vim, ssh

- SSHクライアントOS: Windows10 64bit
- SSHクライアント: MSYS2 ssh
- SSHサーバOS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Vimバージョン: 8.0 (最新バージョンをソースからビルド)

上記の環境で、ターミナル(mintty)からSSH接続しVimを起動すると、ターミナル画面が微動だにせず、Ctrl-Cを押下するとVimの描画が始まります。

**試したが効果がなかったこと**

- .vimrcを削除し、クリーンなVimで起動
- ターミナルをmintty => Teratermに変更
- alias ssh='winpty ssh'

解決策か、試してみる価値の設定はないでしょうか？

```
vim -u NONE --noplugin --startuptime out.txt
```

回答にあった上記のコマンドを試しましたが、効果はありませんでした。
以下out.txtの内容です。inits 3 という所で止まっているようです。

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.003  000.003: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.146  000.143: Allocated generic buffers
000.195  000.049: locale set
000.209  000.014: GUI prepared
000.211  000.002: clipboard setup
000.216  000.005: window checked
000.722  000.506: inits 1
000.729  000.007: parsing arguments
000.730  000.001: expanding arguments
000.740  000.010: shell init
000.986  000.246: Termcap init
001.019  000.033: inits 2
001.130  000.111: init highlight
001.132  000.002: sourcing vimrc file(s)
001.165  000.033: inits 3
11148.633  11147.468: setup clipboard
11148.665  000.032: setting raw mode
11148.686  000.021: start termcap
11148.700  000.014: clearing screen
11151.453  002.753: opening buffers
11151.457  000.004: BufEnter autocommands
11151.461  000.004: editing files in windows
11151.464  000.003: VimEnter autocommands
11151.467  000.003: before starting main loop
11154.031  002.564: first screen update
11154.033  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Comment: `vim -u NONE --noplugin --startuptime out.txt` で起動して、効果があるかどうかの確認と、無かった場合は out.txt を転記してください。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vim -X` で起動してみてください。

ログの内容はクリップボード利用のために X Server へ繋ごうとして時間がかかっていることを示しています。 `-X` オプションは X Server へ接続しないオプションです。

```
11148.633  11147.468: setup clipboard
```

これで改善するようであれば .vimrc に `set clipboard=exclude:.*` を追加すれば、永続化できます。

参考: [vimの起動速度を改善する](http://3100.github.io/blog/2013/07/26/improve-your-vim-performance.html)

Comment: -Xオプションで改善しました。ありがとうございます。

bashrcでSSH接続時には環境変数DISPLAYを設定しているのに、X-ServerをWindows側で起動していなかったのがマズかったようです